# Return Selected Duplicates from Duplicate Pairs

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

On a recent questions I asked to do a join in order to get a list of ALL the duplicates in any duplicate pairs in a table I was provided with this solution:

```
select t1.*, t2.cnt
from TableA t1
join (
  Select FieldA, FieldB, Count(*) as cnt
  from TableA 
  Group By FieldA, FieldB 
  having count(*) > 1
) as t2 on t1.FieldA = t2.FieldA and t1.FieldB = t2.FieldB
```

This worked great and I was able to extract that list

However I now wanted to further refine the list so that I only got results where at least one of the records in the pairs had another field (FieldD) not Null.  Mostly this is one or the other record. In other words I did not want any pairs where FieldD is NULL in both records. So I added to the end of the as t2 query:

```
and (t1.FieldD is not NULL Or t2.FieldD is not null)
```

This almost works except it only returns both records when t1.FieldID is not NULL. When t2.Field is the record that is NOT NULL I only get record 2.

So whereas with the original/inner select duplicates query I was just getting one record for each pair with a count, and with the join select I was, as intended, getting both records in each pair, now that I asked for one or the other to meet the criteria of not being NULL in fieldD I get both records in the pair only when t2.FieldD is the one that is NULL.